# Fast conversion of 3d pyplot figure to matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am working on a project that involves iterative rotation of a 3d object which is built from around 17,000 triangles. For each iteration I need to make af plot of the object and then convert it to a 2d matrix representation.

My first method was to rotate the coordinates of the triangles, make a new 2d figure for each rotation, and convert that to a matrix. But for 17,000 triangles the plotting is too time consuming (~2.3s). Code example:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
# patches are made from vertices with Polygon
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.5)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.canvas.draw()
matrix = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
```

To work around this time consumption I was thinking that I could create a 3d plot once, and then instead of rotating the coordinates of the triangles and then make a new plot, I would just rotate the viewing perspective of the existing 3d plot, and convert the new perspective to a 2d matrix. However, it seems that I have to draw and render the figure for the new perspective before conversion, again causing a too high time consumption (~2.5s). Code example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
for vertex in vertices:
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([vertex]), zs='z')

ax.view_init(10, 90)
fig.canvas.draw()

# grab the pixel buffer and dump it into a numpy array
matrix = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
```

But why do I have to draw or render? If I make an interactive figure, I can make instant rotations by dragging the object. Is there a more clever way to do the conversion?

Comment: Are you implying the when you rotate the figure interactively it will take less than 2.5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, do you disagree?

Comment: If you can show an example where `fig.canvas.draw()` takes more time than rotating a plot with the mouse, one can investigate why that would be. But without any further evidence, one would assume that because rotating the plot with the mouse will eventually call `canvas.draw()` as well, there should not be any difference in timing.